# Issue with connection established from ansible to windows

Tags: ansible, powershell-2.0

WinRM service is already running on this windows machine, but when I run my playbook against a Windows node I'm getting below error.

error:
fatal: [xx:xx:xx:xxx]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host", "unreachable": true}

Could you please let me know if anything is missing or incorrect

Regards,
Priya P

Comment: `Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh_exchange_identification` <= you are using ssh to connect to your host not winrm. You need to set `ansible_connection` to winrm in your inventory, play options or variables.

Answer (score 0):

As [Zeitounator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71661420/issue-with-connection-established-from-ansible-to-windows#comment126654826_71661420) said:

Add winrm connection details. Ie. if you have an ini inventory with a windows group: (put the credentials in a vault)

```
[windows:vars]
ansible_user=<from vault>
ansible_password=<from vault>
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
ansible_port=5986
#ansible_port=5985
ansible_winrm_transport=ntlm
ansible_winrm_scheme=https
#ansible_winrm_scheme=http
```

Comment: @Zeitounator thank you so much for your reply.i will try and let you know